# Javascript: undefined when accesing parent element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to JS and unable to figure out why is my code returning undefined (it is being retuned in the function on assigning ***var tables*** value . What could be wrong?

```
  function showTableAndHideOther(tableCl) {
            var thisTable = document.getElementsByClassName(tableCl);
            var parentEl = thisTable.parentElement;
            var tables = parentEl.getElementsByClassName("warningtable");
            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
                tables[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            thisTable[0].style.display = "";
          }
```

And HTML is:

```
 <div class="expandwarnings" style="display:none">
        <div id="BtnContainer"><button class="btn active" onclick="">Other test</button><button class="btn" onclick="showTableAndHideOther('test')">Filtering test</button></div>
        <table class="warningtable test" style="display:none">
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, besides the undefined value.

Comment: You should add where you call this function, since the `tableCl` argument you passed in will make the `document.getElementsByClassName` find something or not. If it finds nothing, no parent element can exists. Also, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` - which is a sort of array of nodes. They can all have different parents, so `.parentElement` does not exist on this list.

Comment: I want to hide all tables which are under this specific div "expandwarnings". But only under this specific, as I will have several divs with the same class name. This is why I want to find a list of all other tables byfinding the div through parent element

Answer (score 0):

So you cant get the element `warningtable test` by following code

```
var tables = parentEl.getElementsByClassName("warningtable");
```

Chang it to

```
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("warningtable")[0];
```

Comment: The OP is looping over the list of warnings tables, right below this, so this is not causing the issue. The `document.getElementsByClassName` assigned to `thisTable` does have this issue, though.

Comment: This one is easy and works, but not ok for me. I need to specifically find the div in which these tables reside, because there would be several divs with the same class name and tables.

Comment: Great You can accept the answer as sonn as you are able to

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return anything, so you need a return somewhere to get a response to the function call.  But it looks like you just want to format with this function.  Below your code may need a small change.  I believe "thisTable" is an array and that parentRl may not be defined.

```
var thisTable = document.getElementsByClassName(tableCl);
var parentEl = thisTable.parentElement;
```

Can you try the following?

```
var thisTable = document.getElementsByClassName(tableCl);
var parentEl = thisTable[0].parentElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns array.

```
 function showTableAndHideOther(tableCl) {
        var thisTables = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

        for(thisTable of thisTables) {
            var parentEl = thisTable;
            var parentEl = thisTable.parentElement;
            var tables = parentEl.getElementsByClassName("warningtable");
            for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
                tables[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            thisTable.style.display = "";
        }
}
```